# Find potential difference between nodes A and B in circuit below

Tags: resistors, resistance, current-source, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

By KVL and KCL
Ix = 4A and Iy=Iz=6A

The potential difference between A and B = Va - Vb = 6 +8Ix =38V
I don't understand how we calculated the potential difference using KVL and KCL

[image]

Comment: Can you show your work where you calculated Ix, Iy, and Iz?

Comment: Your circuit is ambiguous - try using dots to indicate where nodes join because at the moment it's not clear whether "A" connects to the LH 5 amp source and "B" connects to the RH 5 amp source directly or not. Modify your question's picture to make this unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me this question is abandoned by the author, but I'll give my view anyway as it's a funny one. I assume \$I_x=-I_z\$ and A is only connected to the \$8\,\Omega\$ and the \$6\, V\$ source, i.e.: crosses are no dots.
Then the 2 current sources are in parallel and their series resistors can be neglected, i.e.: there is a current source of \$10 \, A\$ connected from C to D.
From KVL \$8 \, \Omega I_x - 10 \, V - 8 \, \Omega I_y - 6 \, V = 0\$ and from KCL \$I_x + I_y = 10 \, A \$. In other words:

$$ I_x = 10 \, A - I_y \, , \, I_x = 2 \, A +I_y $$
From subtracting the second from the first we have \$ 0 = 8 \, A -2I_y \$ so 
$$ I_y = 4\, A \, , \, I_x = 6\, A$$
making 
$$ U_A - U_B = 6 \, V + 8 \, \Omega I_x = 54 \, V $$